# convert with regexp underscore lowercase word study_one to StudyOne javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this type of words:

```
study_one
orange_two
color_blue...etc.
```

I would like convert this words to:

```
Study One
Orange Two
Color Blue
```

or

```
StudyOne
OrangeTwo
ColorBlue
```

I've been trying with:

```
"study_one".replace(/([A-Z])/g, '_$1').substring(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace spaces with underscores and transform first letter of words to uppercase:

```js
function toCsCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/_/, " ").replace(/(\b[a-z])/g, function(a, b) {
      return a.toUpperCase()
    });
}
console.log(toCsCase("study_one"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this, it should work fine!

```
function toCsCase(str){
    var x = str.split("_");
    var uc = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < x.length;i++)
    {
        uc.push(ucword(x));
    }
    return uc.join(" ");
}
function ucword(word)
{
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: Please with a regexp. It's too much code. thank you!

Comment: It will be a ridiculously big regexp, plus backwards compatibility to older browsers. My answer is logical.

Comment: However if anyone has the RegExp equivalent feel free to comment it

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = 'study_one';

console.log('Result:', doMagic(string));

function doMagic(str) {
    return str

        // capitalize the first letter and all characters after underscore
        .replace(/^(.)|_(.)/g, function($1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); })

        // remove all underscores
        .replace(/_/g, '');
}
```